# PulseAudio channel map at run time

Tags: pulseaudio, bluetooth, ffmpeg

Could I map (Swap) the channel at run time.

I am using the ffmpeg to record the both video and audio from two logitech cam/mic and bluetooth mic. Now currently at the starting of recording bluetooth is off the audio of both the logitech are coming from the left_channel as well as right_channel.And if bluetooth is ON then only the bluetooth audio coming from left_channel and both logitech audio coming from right_channel.

And again off the bluetooth the left_channel gets blank the both logitech audio coming from only right_channel. `So if bluetooth is turned off then I wanted to replace the logitech audio to both the left_channel and right_channel.`

Also if the bluetooth is ON then I set it as default, I have used the following command to set it default:

```
pacmd set-default-source bluez_source.00_1D_DF_44_DB_A6 > /dev/null
```

Also if bluetooth is off then I set the one logitech as default. I used the following command to set it default:

```
pacmd set-default-source alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_D81A0330-00-U0x46d0x823_1.analog-stereo > /dev/null
```

I am using the following ffmpeg command to record the audio and video. This command is generated if at the starting the bletooth is OFF:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel warning -y -f v4l2 -s 544x288 -i /dev/video0 -vstats -vstats_file '/home/left_cam-stats' -f pulse -name 'Unknown source 0' -i alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo -filter lowpass -f pulse -name 'left_mic 0' -i alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_D81A0330-00-U0x46d0x823_1.analog-stereo  -f pulse -name 'right_mic 1' -i alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_4B709030-00-U0x46d0x823.analog-stereo  -f pulse -name 'default 0' -i default  -f mpegts -crf 20 -r 24 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -t 02:00:00 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -map 3:0 -map 4:0 /home/left_cam.mp4
```

If bluetooth is ON at starting the following ffmpeg command is generated.:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel warning -y -f v4l2 -s 544x288 -i /dev/video0 -vstats -vstats_file '/home/left_cam-stats' -f pulse -name 'Unknown source 0' -i alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo -filter lowpass -f pulse -name 'left_mic 0' -i alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_D81A0330-00-U0x46d0x823_1.analog-stereo  -f pulse -name 'right_mic 1' -i alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_4B709030-00-U0x46d0x823.analog-stereo  -f pulse -name 'default 0' -i bluez_source.00_1D_DF_44_DB_A6  -f mpegts -crf 20 -r 24 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -t 02:00:00 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -map 3:0 -map 4:0 /home/left_cam.mp4
```

I want to replace the logitech audio to both left_channel and right_channel if bluetooth is off and if bluetooth is On then only the bluetooth audio from left_channel and both logitech from the right_channel.